# How can I find double spacing in string split?

Tags: python, string, split, double, space

I have a text file that I need to encode and decode using the Huffman encoding through python. However, I need to split the strings based on words and I need to keep the spacing for decoding. However, if I use the normal .split(" ") function it assumes the double space as a single space. I need to store the strings as the image below. Is there any way how I can keep the double spacing?

The image below is what I want to implement

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

print([ y for x in phrase.split(" ") for y in (x," ") if y != "" ][:-1])

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
>>> import re
>>> phrase = " whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it"
>>> result = re.findall('[\s]|[^\s]+', phrase)
[' ', 'whatsoever.', ' ', ' ', 'You', ' ', 'may', ' ', 'copy', ' ', 'it,', ' ', 'give', ' ', 'it']
```